# C# generate image dynamically and set it as ItemMenuStrip Image

Tags: c#, image, dynamically-generated

What I am trying to accomplish is to generate dynamically an image and add it to ItemMenuStrip as image. It works when I set it as background image but fails when I am trying to set it as image. What I am doing wrong here?

Code:

```
foreach (ColorData colordata in colors)
        {

            ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem
            {
                Image = GenerateColorImage(colordata.UserSelectedColor),
                Text = colordata.ColorDescription,
                ToolTipText = "Click to change color",
                Tag = num
            };

            item.Click += (sender, e) => { setScreenColors_Click(sender, e, colors); };
            list.Add(item);
            num++;
           // item.Dispose();
        }

private Bitmap GenerateColorImage(Color color)
    {
        Bitmap colorimage = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(colorimage))
        {
            graphics.Clear(color);
        }
        return colorimage;
    }
```

Comment: My fault. items.Dispose(); caused this problem. I had to comment this out.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This might be what you're looking for ,

```
private Bitmap GenerateColorImage(Color color)
        {
            Bitmap colorimage = new Bitmap(16, 16) ;
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(colorimage))
            {
                graphics.Clear(color);
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colorimage)
                {
                   graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 16, 16);
                }

            }
            return colorimage;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I compiles but items in menu are not created at all.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work but looks like problem is not within GenerateColorImage function but with function that generates dynamically menu items. Thanx for help anyways ;)